# Parsing text after bold tag using XPath

Tags: python, xpath

I am extracting text using Xpath in Python.
The structure of the text is as follows:

```
<b>Field1:</b>" Value1" <br>
<b>Field2:</b>" Value2" <br><br>
<b>Field3:</b>" Value3" <br><br>
<b>Field4:</b>" Value4" <br>
<b>Field5:</b>" Value5" <br><br>
```

Note that number of line break (br tag) can be inconsistent

I want to extract:

```
Field 1: Value 1
Field 2: Value 2
Field 3: Value 3
Field 4: Value 4
Field 5: Value 5
```

Currently my XPath //b/text() is extracting the Fields but not the Values.

Please help.

Comment: ValueX is not linked with any tag ??

Comment: @PankajKatiyar no it is not linked with any tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) HTML parser and it's [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
<b>Field1:</b>" Value1" <br>
<b>Field2:</b>" Value2" <br><br>
<b>Field3:</b>" Value3" <br><br>
<b>Field4:</b>" Value4" <br>
<b>Field5:</b>" Value5" <br><br>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for b in soup.find_all("b"):
    label = b.get_text(strip=True)
    value = b.next_sibling.strip()

    print(label, value)
```

Or, with [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) and [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """
<div>
<b>Field1:</b>" Value1" <br>
<b>Field2:</b>" Value2" <br><br>
<b>Field3:</b>" Value3" <br><br>
<b>Field4:</b>" Value4" <br>
<b>Field5:</b>" Value5" <br><br>
</div>
"""

root = fromstring(data)
for b in root.xpath("//b"):
    label = b.text_content()
    value = b.xpath("following-sibling::text()")[0].strip()

    print(label, value)
```

Comment: The [0].strip() is throwing a "IndexError: list index out of range" exception but when I remove it, it works.

Comment: @Ram ah, yeah, I was assuming every `b` tag has a following text sibling - this might be not true for your input data.

Comment: Thank you for providing 2 solutions. BeautifulSoup looks much more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `lxml`, you can get the text that follows the element using `tail` attribue:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>>
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring('''
... <html>
...     <body>
...         <b>Field1:</b>" Value1" <br>
...         <b>Field2:</b>" Value2" <br><br>
...         <b>Field3:</b>" Value3" <br><br>
...         <b>Field4:</b>" Value4" <br>
...         <b>Field5:</b>" Value5" <br><br>
...     </body>
... </html>
... ''')
>>> for b in root.xpath('//b'):
...     print('{} {}'.format(b.text, b.tail.strip('" ')))  # <---
...
Field1: Value1
Field2: Value2
Field3: Value3
Field4: Value4
Field5: Value5
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution.